# Exibir arquivo php no body de um email

Tags: php, libcurl, phpmailer, envio-de-email, file-get-contents

Estou utilizando o PHPmailer para o envio de emails, quero encapsular o conteúdo de uma página em php no campo: $mail->Body, essa página que deve ser incluída no body faz busca na api de rastreamento dos correios e retorno os dados de maneira tratada.
Já tentei usar o file_get_contents mas não funciounou porque a página a ser inserida faz uma requisição.
Tentei o curl mas não me dá o retorno esperado, retorna uma string com a quantidade de caracteres ou então "resource id#7".[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<?php

    session_start();

    require "./biblioteca/PHPmailer/Exception.php";
    require "./biblioteca/PHPmailer/OAuth.php";
    require "./biblioteca/PHPmailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require "./biblioteca/PHPmailer/POP3.php";
    require "./biblioteca/PHPmailer/SMTP.php";

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    class Mensagem {

        public $status = array('codigo_status' => null, 'descricao_status' => '');
    
        public function __get($atributo) {
            return $this->$atributo;
        }
        public function __set($atributo, $valor) {
            $this->$atributo = $valor;
        }
    }
    


    $mensagem = new Mensagem();

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);


    $url = "http://localhost/e-lastic/e-lastic-brasil/template_email.php";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $rastreio = curl_exec($ch);
    
    
    try {
        //Server settings
          ...
        // Attachments
                                     
        $mail->addAttachment('pdf.php', 'email.pdf');         // Add attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = "Sua encomenda chegou";
        $mail->Body    = 

        var_dump($rastreio);
    
        $mail->AltBody = 'Necessário usar um client que suporte HTML para ter acesso total ao conteúdo dessa mensagem';

        $mail->send();

        $mensagem->status['codigo_status'] = 1;
        $mensagem->status['descricao_status'] = 'Email enviado com sucesso!';

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $mensagem->status['codigo_status'] = 2;
        $mensagem->status['descricao_status'] = 'Não foi possível enviar esse email! Detalhes do erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/mdb.min.css">

</head>

<body>


    <div class="modal fade" id="exemplomodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <? if ($mensagem->status['codigo_status'] == 1) { ?>

                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <h1 class="display-4 text-success">
                                            Sucesso
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <p>
                                    <?= $mensagem->status['descricao_status'] ?>
                                </p>


                                <a href="http://gabrielquintino.scprojetista.com/"
                                    class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-5 text-white">Voltar
                                </a>

                            </div>

                            <? } ?>

                            <? if ($mensagem->status['codigo_status'] == 2) { ?>

                            <div class="container">
                                <h1 class="display-4 text-danger">
                                    Ops!
                                </h1>
                                <p>
                                    <?= $mensagem->status['descricao_status'] ?>
                                </p>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="http://gabrielquintino.scprojetista.com/"
                                        class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mt-5 text-white">Voltar
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <? } ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- END MODAL -->

    <!-- end pedir meu chip -->
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#exemplomodal').modal('show');
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O `var_dump` foi só para verificar a saída de dados? Já tentou sem ele?

Comment: Isso, só pra exibir o resultado, já tentei com printf tbm mas não funciona, com o echo nem é permitido.

Comment: Tenta usar `ob_start()` e `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: Você não vai conseguir por o codigo php dentro do body e esperar que ele execute em algum momento, você tem que renderizar o resultado, pegar o html gerado e por no body.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tentar bastante, consegui renderizar o conteúdo no próprio

```html
<?$mail->Body    = 
    
    '<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://elastic.fit/">
        <img src="http://e-lastic.scprojetista.com/logo-color-small.png" width="150" height="30" alt="logo" />
    </a><hr /><br />'.'
    <h3 style="color: #0c80a3">
        <img src="http://e-lastic.scprojetista.com/icone.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="ícone" />'.    
        $titulo.'
    </h3>'.'
    <p>Você pode acompanhar o envio com o códio de rastreamento
        <a href="https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/default.cfm">'.
        $_SESSION['obj'].
        '</a><br />
    </p>';
    if ($rastreio[0]['action'] === "Objeto entregue ao destinatário") {
        $mail->Body   .= 
            '<img src="http://e-lastic.scprojetista.com/entregue.jpg" width="400" height="40" alt="">';
        }
    elseif($rastreio[0]['action'] === "Objeto em trânsito - por favor aguarde"){
        $mail->Body   .= 
            '<img src="http://e-lastic.scprojetista.com/encaminhando.png" width="400" height="40" alt="logo" />';
        }
    else {
        $mail->Body   .= '<img src="http://e-lastic.scprojetista.com/horario_limite.jpg" width="400" height="40" alt="logo" />';
        }

    foreach($rastreio as $key=> $obj){
    
    $mail->Body   .= 

    '<hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>';
            if ($obj['date'] !== 'O') {
                $mail->Body   .= 
                $obj['date']."<br />". $obj['hour']."<br />". $obj['location'];
            }
            $mail->Body   .= 
            '</td>
             <td>';
             if ($obj['date'] !== 'O') {
                $mail->Body   .= 
                $obj['message'];
             }
             $mail->Body   .= 
            '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar fazer da maneira abaixo, acredito que seja a melhor maneira sem usar frameworks.

```
ob_start();


/**
** Minha classe pra enviar email usando phpmailer
** 
**/
$alerta = new ControllerEmail();

$alerta->addAtachImage(getRoot("/assets/img/logos/logo-email.png"), "logo");

/**
** Variável assunto é requerida no arquivo view.email.contrato-analize.php
** @var @assunto
**/
$assunto = "Assunto teste";

require viewsPathEmail("view.email.contrato-analize.php");

/**
** Essa variável $resultsHTML você pode por em $mail->Body = $resultsHTML;
**
*/
$resultsHTML = ob_get_clean();
```